# Create HTTPS-based Encrypted URLs Using Routes for Starter subscription

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3

I am trying to follow this article [Create HTTPS-based Encrypted URLs Using Routes](https://blog.openshift.com/create-https-based-encrypted-urls-using-routes/).  Will I be able to accomplish this on a Starter subscription account?

Specifically, I tried to login using OC tool with ‘oc login’.  But it asked for server.  I am not sure where to get this server url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to:

- https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/

and go through the mini tutorial there:

- https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/cluster-access/

It will explain to you how you can login to an OpenShift cluster from web console and command line.